# what size or type of supercapacitor bank would be needed to run a TURNIGY ROTOMAX 150cc electric motor?

Tags: capacitor, supercapacitor

What size or type of supercapacitor bank would be needed to run a TURNIGY ROTOMAX 150cc electric motor?

Spec.:

```
Battery: 14 Cell / 51.8V
RPM: 150kv
Max current: 190A
Watts: 9800w
No load current: 51.8V/5.2A
Internal resistance: 0.011 ohm
Weight: 2530g
Diameter of shaft: 10mm
Winding: 8T
Stator Pole: 24
Motor Pole: 20
Stator Diameter: 101
Lamination Tickness: 0.2mm
Suggested ESC: 250A 14S Compatible
```

Comment: How long do you want to run it for?

Comment: What Im trying to do is have this 150cc Turnigy outrunner motor run a small go kart as a hybrid connected to a bank of supercapacitors that are constantly being charged by generator connected to a small gas engine. Please let me know if you can think of anything.  Thank You

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't answered my question. You'll want to work out how long you want to run the motor continuously before the capacitors run out of power before we can say what kind or how many capacitors you need.

Answer (score 2):

We can't answer this because you haven't given us enough information, but it's not difficult to work out from the basics.

Capacitors store charge, which is measured in Coulombs - which is another way of saying Amp-Seconds.

So, you need to know how many amps the motor needs, and how many seconds you want it to run for on this stored charge. Multiply those to get the charge you need in Coulombs - call this number Q1

Now you will charge the capacitor to a start voltage V1, and the voltage will reduce as you draw charge from it. At some point, the reduced voltage (call it V2) will have slowed the motor to the point where it no longer does the job. You can calculate these voltages from the speed you need and the motor constant Kv.

So you need a capacitor big enough to store Q1 coulombs between V1 and V2.

Now Q = CV, or C = Q/V, so the capacitance you need is:

C = Q1 / (V1 - V2) farads.

And obviously the capacitor must be rated for the maximum voltage, V1.

Now just substitute in the numbers you haven't told us, and there's your answer.

Comment: Thanks Brian Drummond. What I want to do is build a mini hybrid go kart (lol) I want to use this 150cc outrunner motor to run the kart and combine it with a set or bank of supercapicitors that are constantly being charged by a generator of some sort that is run by a small gas engine. I know this doesnt make sense but if there is a way to do this please let me know and please be wide open with me on what obstacles I may face and what calculations I must do.

Comment: I saw a video on YOUTUBE where a guy had a small fan connected to some supercaps which were connected to a small generator/motor thing that he spun by hand. Just kinda want to recreate the same thing no matter the cost.